# mysqli inserts typed values but not variables

Tags: variables, mysqli, insert

I have tried to get the following code to work. It is an ajax-call where I send a json-encoded string 'data':

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php'); // get values for mysqli-connect
        $arr1 = json_decode($_GET['data']);
        $arr = array_values($arr1);

if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($server,$user,$pw,$db);
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    //values to be inserted in database table
    $var1 = "Hello World";
    $var2 = 45;
    $var3 = "an encoded array";
/*
    $var1 = $arr[1];
    $var2 = $arr[2];
    $var3 = json_encode($arr[3]);
*/
    $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table_testing 
        (event, pid, myarray) VALUES ('$var1', '$var2', '$var3')");

    if($insert_row){
    print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$mysqli->insert_id .'<br />';
    }else{
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
    }
 } else {
    echo "User is NOT logged in!\n";
}   
?>
```

My problem is that this code works! It works fine with the three values that are stored in $var1-3. They are saved in the correct table.

But - if I try to store the out-commented three values from $arr[1-3] into $var[1-3] it doesn't work? The three values saved are ' ' (empty), '0' and 'NULL'.
I have tried to put these lines in right after $arr is declared:

```
echo $arr[1]."\n";
echo $arr[2]."\n";
echo json_encode($arr[3])."\n";
```

In the console the correct values are printed, so they are valid and exist. It is a string, an integer and an array.
What is it I have overlooked or not understood?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes of PHP [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) start are 0-based.

Try with this code:

```
echo $arr[0] . "\n";
echo $arr[1] . "\n";
echo json_encode($arr[2]) . "\n";
```

Comment: I know it is 0-based. The value in $arr[0] is a string, but in the table it is defined as an int. Until that is fixed, I do not use the first value. Right now I'm only testing. Thanks all the same.